# Add new lambda expressions using Expression Tree

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have been looking at many posts here and on the web but none of them seem to be helping.

I have a table with about 2 million records, it has over 200 columns.

A simple web service allow the user to pull a specific number of columns out of the table, the user has the option to choose which column to pull.

The result needs to be string of comma separated values, so my query needs to pull the requested columns and return a concatenate string.

I have done this using ADO.NET and pure SQL queries it works fine however I was asked to do it in Entity Framework.

Here is what I have and have done already.

I get the requested columns list as an array of strings.

The following is my query, not sure if it's the best solution or idea hence I'm asking for help here.

```
var valueList2 = ctx.mytable.Where(x => x.pcds == comValue).Select(x => new{temp = x.column1 +", "+ x.column2}).Select(x => x.temp).ToList();
```

The above gives me string of two columns separated by commas, I just need to somehow push my array of column names into the lambda part of it.

I did the following but then realised that it only works with a specific type of a class not anonymous, also I can't figure out how I can use it for a multiple columns and not make it so complex.

```
var createdType = typeof(mytable);
var Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "pr");
var obj = Expression.New(createdType);
var ValueProperty = createdType.GetProperty("long");
var ValueAssignment = Expression.Bind(ValueProperty, Param);
var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(obj, ValueAssignment);
var lm = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, mytable>>(memberInit, Param);
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want to do the string concatenation SQL side? This is probably a recipe for problems... Sadly even doing it C# side is complex :-)

Comment: You don't need 2 selects, single `.Select(x =>  x.a + ", " + x.b + ...)` would be enough. But as @xanatos mentioned, it would format the numbers, dates with who knows (basically database controlled) format.

Comment: @IvanStoev And for strings you are hoping that there are no `Hello, world` as values :-)

Comment: Well, I think the best way to do it is to create a store procedure and input the array of columns then use FOR XML PATH to concatenate the results, but again the problem is that I can't access the SQL server so everything has to be done in C# and EF.

Comment: @xanatos Ah, indeed! :)

Comment: CLR Stored Proc could be the easiest...

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried to use only one select but it doesn't let me convert to string so I had to treat it as an anonymous object then call that object in another select. all the data are just simple strings, there is no sentence there, so no commas or illegal characters.

Comment: @Farshad The main problem here is that you can't create an anonymous object at runtime in an easy way. You can create a new type (a new `class` to make it simple)... But if you create this new type, then it remains loaded in memory... So after two or three weeks you will have in memory perhaps hundred of anonymous types that you have used once or twice...

Comment: So I consider both solutions (string concatenation SQL-side and creating types on-the-fly) bad solutions. Sadly I don't think that EF has a "return an  `IEnumerable<object[]>`. That would be the perfect solution

Comment: What version of EF are you using? So that I can do some experiments... It is an interesting question...

Comment: @xanatos I see, it makes sense. How about EF's SqlQuery method can I just run my query in there and somehow convert the returned data into concatenated string?
It's EF6, thanks

Comment: @Farshad Probably not... From what I see you need to pass an object type to be used as a row...

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658712/entity-framework-raw-sql-query-selecting-unknown-columns-unknown-return-type

Comment: Yeah I see, I thought about pulling everything and cut out the columns I don't want but then that wouldn't be a good solution, I kind of think maybe expression trees are the only right way but they are way too complex.

Comment: Expressions are Overkill for this just use XML FOR in a sproc...

Comment: @JeremyThompson It isn't expression that are overkill... It's EF that is the wrong tool for the problem. This is a classical problem where Ado.NET and a `DbDataReader` work perfectly well. EF isn't built for doing these things. With NHibernate it would be quite easy (using the CriteriaAPI and a projection to `object[]`).

Comment: Yeah EF is, you just need to use a stored procedure. If you're​ working with an ORM which typically has sproc support for these exact things.

Comment: @xanatos what would you recommend? Code base and tests are all EF. Nhiberate?

Comment: @JeremyThompson There is no "perfect" solution here... I'll post a possible solution...

Comment: @xanatos would you be able to explain how to go about this using NHibernate, I don't have any experience with that. Thanks
----
Sorry just realised that its open source equivalent of EF, that wouldn't help me.

Comment: @Farshad NHibernate is another ORM, similar to Entity Framework, but let's say that it is another religion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Dynamic Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) ([source code](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)). Sadly there is little documentation about how to use it :-) In a fun boomerang effect, [there is an "evolved" version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/). The boomerang effect is because the code for generating the dynamic class is based on one of my responses :-) The remaining code seems to be very beautiful... And there is a [full suit of unit tests with code samples!!!](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/tree/master/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests) Note that this second library is a superset of the first library, so you can probably apply many examples to the first one! :-)

I'm adding some static methods to translate the result of a a Dynamic Linq query to a `IEnumerable<object[]>`.... Example code:

```
using (var ctx = new Model1())
{
    var result = ctx.MyTable
        .Take(100)
        .SimpleSelect(new[] { "ID", "Col1", "Col2" })
        .ToObjectArray();

    foreach (var row in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row));
    }
}
```

More complex example:

```
var columnsNames = new[] { "SomeNullableInt32", "SomeNonNullableDateTimeColumn" };

// One for each column!
var formatters = new Func<object, string>[]
{
    x => x != null ? x.ToString() : null,
    x => ((DateTime)x).ToShortDateString()
};

var result = ctx.MyTable.Take(100).SimpleSelect(columnsNames).ToObjectArray();

foreach (var row in result)
{
    var stringRow = new string[row.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
    {
        stringRow[i] = formatters[i](row[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", stringRow));
}
```

And the classes... One (`SimpleSelect`) produces the Dynamic SQL Select, and "anonymizes" the field names. I do this because for each type of return the Dynamic Linq will generate at runtime a class. This class won't be unloaded until the program ends. By anonymizing the columns (I rename them to `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3`...) I increase the possibility that the same class will be reused. Note that different type of columns will generate different classes! (`int Item1, string Item2` will be a different class from `int Item1, DateTime Item2`), the other (`ToObjectArray`) returns a `IEnumerable<object[]>`, something easier to parse.

```
public static class DynamicLinqTools
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, object[]>> Converters = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<object, object[]>>();

    public static IQueryable SimpleSelect(this IQueryable query, string[] fields)
    {
        // With a little luck, "anonymizing" the field names we should 
        // reduce the number of types created!
        // new (field1 as Item1, field2 as Item2)
        return query.Select(string.Format("new ({0})", string.Join(", ", fields.Select((x, ix) => string.Format("{0} as Item{1}", x, ix + 1)))));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> ToObjectArray(this IQueryable query)
    {
        Func<object, object[]> converter;

        Converters.TryGetValue(query.ElementType, out converter);

        if (converter == null)
        {
            var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "row");

            // ElementType row2;
            var row2 = Expression.Variable(query.ElementType, "row2");

            // (ElementType)row;
            var cast = Expression.Convert(row, query.ElementType);

            // row2 = (ElementType)row;
            var assign = Expression.Assign(row2, cast);

            var properties = query.ElementType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(x => x.CanRead && x.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                .ToArray();

            // (object)row2.Item1, (object)row2.Item2, ...
            var properties2 = Array.ConvertAll(properties, x => Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(row2, x), typeof(object)));

            // new object[] { row2.Item1, row2.Item2 }
            var array = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), properties2);

            // row2 = (ElementType)row; (return) new object[] { row2.Item1, row2.Item2 }
            var body = Expression.Block(typeof(object[]), new[] { row2 }, assign, array);

            var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object[]>>(body, row);
            converter = exp.Compile();

            Converters.TryAdd(query.ElementType, converter);
        }

        foreach (var row in query)
        {
            yield return converter(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like the solution at least in EF. So if I could access SQL server, which would you recommend this or stored procedure?

Comment: @Farshad Aaaaah... I cant' select between bad1 and bad2... A dynamic query made in a SP through `eval` is bad2... This code is bad1... :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a short and easy answer for whoever needs a different answer, but per our discussion with @xanatos, it's not the best as it also returns all the columns which need to be cut off before adding to a list of strings.

```
List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
using (var ctx = new DataEntities1())
{
    var query = ctx.myTable.Where(x => x.pcds == scode).SingleOrDefault();

    foreach (var item in columnsArray)
    {
        valueList.Add(typeof(myTable).GetProperty(onsColumns[Convert.ToInt32(item)]).GetValue(query).ToString());
    }
}
```